# How to set a a reducer to emmit <Text, IntWritable> and a mapper to receive <Text, IntWritable>?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm developing some code on **hadoop** with **mapreduce** that uses **two mappers and two reducers.**
I've been told to use **SequenceFileInputFormat** and **SequenceFileOutputFormat** to make the output of the first reducer and the input of the second mapper to work together.
The problem is that i'm recibing an error and after *googleing* a lot i don't know why.

**The error:**

> java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: **expected** org.apache.hadoop.io.**IntWritable**, **received** org.apache.hadoop.io.**Text**
>
> Type mismatch in key from **map**: **expected**
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.**IntWritable**, **received** org.apache.hadoop.io.**Text**

**The code:**

```
package casoTaxis;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;

public class Eje1{

    public static class MapperJob1 extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        //El metodo map recibe un conjunto clave-valor, lo procesa y lo vuelca en un contexto.adasdadada 
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Text hackLicense; IntWritable totalAmount; //salidas
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",");
            itr.nextToken();
            hackLicense = new Text(itr.nextToken());
            for(int i=2; i<itr.countTokens(); i++) itr.nextToken();
            totalAmount = new IntWritable( Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken()) );
            context.write(hackLicense, totalAmount);
        }
    }

    public static class ReducerJob1 extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> { //No encontre una clase InpuFormat que sea Text, IntWritable
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static class MapperJob2 extends Mapper<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        //El metodo map recibe un conjunto clave-valor, lo procesa y lo vuelca en un contexto.adasdadada 
        public void map(Text key, IntWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(key, value);
        }
    }

    public static class ReducerJob2 extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int max = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                int maxVal = val.get();
                if( maxVal>max ) max = maxVal;
            }
            String licencia = "Conductor con licencia = " + key;
            String recaudacion = "Recaudacion = " + max;
            context.write(new Text(licencia), new Text(recaudacion));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
        Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
        //conf2.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", " ");
        Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf1, "Eje1-Job1");
        Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "Eje1-Job2");
        job1.setJarByClass(Eje1.class);
        job2.setJarByClass(Eje1.class);
        job1.setMapperClass(MapperJob1.class);
        job2.setMapperClass(MapperJob2.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(ReducerJob1.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(ReducerJob2.class);

        job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job1.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
        job2.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);///asdasdads

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, pathIntermedio);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, pathIntermedio);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));

        job1.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    private static final Path pathIntermedio = new Path("intermediate_output");

}
```

**Why i'm receiving this error? is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the lines

```
job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job2.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
```

The second of those should be:

```
job2.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```